# Kepler's 3rd law/law of periods

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

Kepler's 3rd law of planetary motion is

> The square of the time period of a planet orbiting a sun is proportional to the cube of the semi major axis of the elliptical orbit.

$$(T_1)^2   =   (A_1)^3,$$

[link](http://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/stargaze/Kep3laws.htm)

But in many other sites it (the square of the time period) is said to be proportional to the mean radius of the elliptical orbit.

$$(T_1)^2   =   (R_1)^3,$$

[link](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-4/Kepler-s-Three-Laws)

which one is correct? Or is there a relation between the mean radius and the semi major axis which cancel out because of proportionality?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes#Ellipse

Answer (score 2):

From [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes),

> It is often said that the semi-major axis is the "average" distance
>   between the primary focus of the ellipse and the orbiting body. This
>   is not quite accurate, because it depends on what the average is taken
>   over.
>
> averaging the distance over the eccentric anomaly indeed results in  the semi-major axis.
>
> averaging over the true anomaly (the true orbital angle, measured at
>   the focus) results, oddly enough, in the semi-minor axis
>   ${\displaystyle b=a{\sqrt {1-e^{2}}}}$.
>
> averaging over the mean anomaly (the fraction of the orbital period that has elapsed since pericentre, expressed as an angle), finally, gives the time-average ${\displaystyle a\left(1+{\frac{e^{2}}{2}}\right)}$.
>
> The time-averaged value of the reciprocal of the radius, ${\displaystyle r^{-1}}$, is ${\displaystyle a^{-1}}$.